# show ANSI color in Xcode4 debug console

Tags: ios, xcode4

Is there any way to do this?
I wan't to distinguish my Logs by different colors.

Comment: You most likely are referring to ANSI colors - ASCII does not define any color codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To enable ANSI colors in Xcode console** install clone https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors and build. The build process will install the Xcode plugin in the proper directory.

**To unsign Xcode** clone https://github.com/steakknife/unsign, run make, put the unsign command in the path. Then run the following:

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS
sudo unsign Xcode
sudo mv Xcode Xcode.signed
sudo ln -sf Xcode.unsigned Xcode
```

Note that this is reversible. Just change the symbolic link. Now you need to **update the plugin UUID to match the current Xcode version**:

```
XCODEUUID=`defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`

for f in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*; do defaults write "$f/Contents/Info" DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add $XCODEUUID; done
```

Now you can use ANSI colors in your Xcode console. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that I direct log to a file or logger in my code or there is any way I can directly redirect xcode's console to a custom console?

Comment: You can't redirect the Xcode console. You have to replace your NSLog calls with your custom code (eg: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11581286/412916) replacing `fprintf(stdout...` with `FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "w"); fprintf(file...` ), or use a library like CocoaLumberjack.

Comment: @Jano there is no need to redirect anything - NSLog is fine. The console output of your app actually goes directly into the system log - see the OSX Console.app and select "system.log" while debugging your iOS app.

Comment: That file is available at /private/var/log/system.log but it contains logs from several applications and OS X components. It may be best to output to a private file and tail it in the terminal to display ANSI colors.

Comment: I installed the plugin, the test project works, but I can't get it to display colors in another project. What else do I have to do ?

Comment: I think the OP was asking how to have the "internal" terminal in xCode display colors. I know how to display ANSI colors on a regular terminal, but the same code is black and white with the ANSI codes rendered literally in xCode debug session.

Comment: @ThomasJayRush The colors above are a screenshot of Xcode console. I updated the instructions for Xcode 8.

Comment: I downloaded. It compiled perfectly. The plugin appeared in the right folder. Closed Xcode, reloaded, re-build the test program and got this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZjeE.png

Comment: Xcode 8 won’t download any plugins until you unsign it. If you unsign it, and  update the UUID (see script above) you will see a dialog asking you whether to load the bundle of the plugin. That dialog looks like this: https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/1447760274Pic_1.png

Comment: The [mylcode fork](https://github.com/mylcode/XcodeColors) of this worked for me with unsigned Xcode 8.3.3 - thanks!